# finding bottom position of html element and putting inner element at the bottom of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Updated**

I am trying to put html div tag at the bottom of the its parent div tag. Forexample, I have div tag and using jquery I am creating another div tag and trying it to put it at the bottom  of the div tag which is already visible in the document. I am trying this with below code but doesnt work. It does not put the div tag at the bottom of available div tag.

```
var self = $(this);
        var sh = $('<div></div>');
        var bgshadow = $(sh).css({
            'position'              :    'absolute',
                'width'                 :    self.outerWidth(),
                'height'                :    30, //self.outerHeight() - 180,
                'left'                  :    self.offset().left,
                'top'                   :    self.height() - sh.height(), //self.offset().top,
                //'bottom'              :    self.height() - sh.height(),                    
                '-webkit-box-shadow'    :    '0px 15px 20px #000000',
                '-moz-box-shadow'       :    '0px 15px 20px #000000',
                'box-shadow'            :    '0px 15px 20px #000000',
                'border-radius'         :    '25px',
                'z-index'               :    1
        }).appendTo(self.parent());
```

**Edited**

Please check it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttX3w/)

Can someone tell me why is it not working?

Comment: you want to move div tag from any position to last position?

Answer (score 1):

replace

`'top' :   self.height() - sh.height(), //self.offset().top`

with

`bottom: 0`

It will sit at the bottom of its parent.

Also `left:0` is sufficient for the div to sit on the left which is what you seem to be trying to do.

Just make sure the parent is positioned with absolute or relative positioning.

Comment: Only if the parent is also the offset parent.  Tip: set `position: relative;` on the parent.

Comment: Sorry. It will not be placed inside its parent div tag. So its parent is document. Your solution place it at the bottom of the whole document.

Comment: @alOne: What are you talking about? its new parent is the element it is appended to, where did you get document from? EDIT: Oh right, you are assuming the parent is document probably because you didn't position the parent, right?

Answer (score 1):

Does the parent div have a CSS position of relative or absolute? You'll need that. And then you can just use

```
'bottom': '0px'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the parent div containing the target  div has position relative and the target div has position absolute with left: 0 and bottom: 0.
Instead of making use inline style, it would be a good practice to use CSS class.
Your DOM structure should be something like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .border {border:1px solid #000;}
      .parent{height:300px;position:relative;}
      .target{height:100px;width:300px;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent border">
      parent
      <div class="target border">
        target
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, I tried exactly what you have, and it works !!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/8UCKm/1/